# Why do I get MobileCapabilities while in windows & MAC?

Tags: .net, http, http-headers

I am getting all the time:
UAGENT: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/8.0.552.224 Safari/534.10 BROWSER: System.Web.Mobile.MobileCapabilities HOST: 67.142.173.27

How can it be windows NT 6.0 with MobileCapabilities???

Those calls do me some trouble... can it be crawler of some type?

Answer (score 0):

User-agent line looks like Google Chrome one (you can check it at http://user-agents.my-addr.com/user_agent_request/user_agent_examples-and-user_agent_types.php)
However, how MobileCapabilities appeared there, that is a question, that class should be used from ASP.NET server side, not from client's one.